# SQL query to get a list of all elements belonging to a group that every element belongs to

Tags: mysql, sql

The intention is to be able to show all episodes for any show that a character has been a part of whether or not that character was in the episode itself.

I have the following tables...

*Character*

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | brain |
| 2 | pinky |
| 3 | dot |

*Show*

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pinky & The Brain |
| 2 | Animaniacs |

*Profile*

| id | character | show |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |

*Episode*

| id | character | name | is_shareable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Clocktower | True |
| 2 | 2 | Escape | False |
| 3 | 3 | Return of the Jedi | True |

I am trying to produce a query result that looks like this by selecting all characters in the same show for every character and the associated show

*CharacterEpisode*

| user | show | episode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

I can do something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UserEpisode AS
SELECT
       c.id as character_id,
       s.id as show_id,
       e.id as episode_id
from character as c
     join profile as p on p.character_id = c.id
     join show as s on p.show_id = s.id
     join show as qs on p.show_id = qs.id
     join profile as qp on qp.show_id = qs.id
     join episode as e on qp.character_id = e.character_id;
```

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. How would I modify this to include the episode.is_shareable column so that the view reflects directly associated is-shareable = False episodes and all is_shareable = True episodes that have any of the characters in the show for output that looks like:

| user | show | episode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Your desired results (if that's what it is) columns don't relate to your source data? What does non-shareable mean? I don't see any column named sharable or similar.

Comment: Fixed for the missing is_shareable column in table `episode`.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the ids,. you don't need neither charater nor show

Only when you want the na,es you need to join them once

you can exclude the not sharacle, simple by adding a `WHERE` clause

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UserEpisode AS
SELECT
       p.character as character_id,
       p.show as show_id,
       e.id as episode_id
from      profile as p 
     join episode as e on p.character_id = e.character_id;
WHERE e.is_shareable = 'True'
```

eveb whewnb you want the shows name an characternames, you would make it simpler

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UserEpisode AS
SELECT
       p.character as character_id,
       p.show as show_id,
       e.id as episode_id
from profile as p 
     join show as s on p.show_id = s.id
     join character as c ON p.character_id = c.id
     join episode as e on p.character_id = e.character_id;
WHERE e.is_shareable = 'True'
```

If you want to see all charcters you can make such a query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UserEpisode AS
SELECT
       p.character as character_id,
       p.show as show_id,
       e.id as episode_id
from character as c
     LEFT JOIN profile as p ON p.character_id = c.id
     LEFT join show as s on p.show_id = s.id
     LEFT join episode as e on p.character_id = e.character_id;
WHERE e.is_shareable = 'True' OR e.is_shareable IS NULL
```

Comment: This does not return episode_id for all episodes of a show for all characters that are on the show whether or not they are explicitly linked to the episode on table `episode`.

Comment: your query would either shows those characters, but i added another query that would show all characters, but you didn't asked for that

Comment: I want a denormalized table with rows showing every episode of every show that a character has been in even if they are not explicitly connected with the episode and only the show. This doesn't seem to do it.

Also, the is_shareable is meant to pick up shareable episodes that others did and is ignored for self.